# Measuring internet performance

Tags: networking, internet, performance, statistics

Is there a program that measures the performance (bandwidth, latency) of my internet connection over time? I'm interested in trends, statistics, etc... I suspect that I'm not getting all that I'm paying for from my ISP.

Answer (score 4):

You can use tests such as http://www.speedtest.net and http://www.pingtest.net to check your bandwidth, pings, latency and connection strength. You'd have to do these manually and log your stats yourself, but done properly it would give you a nice picture of your connection over time.

Comment: I prefer fast.com, it's hosted by Netflix.

Answer (score -3):

There is this one tool used by tweakers like me, called wifi analyzer.
WiFi Analyzer can help you to identify Wi-Fi problems, find the best channel or the best place for your router/access-point by turning your PC/laptop, tablet or mobile device into an analyzer for your wireless network.
It also has a bunch of built in tools.

Here's the link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/wifi-analyzer/9nblggh33n0n?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0&activetab=pivot:overviewtab

This is an outside link, just to let you know anything and everything that occurs is not my responsibility. Though it's shown by Microsoft, so I'm sure you'll be ok.

Hope this helps.